# Laravel Passport, multiple connexions via password client

Tags: laravel

I am having troubles understanding how could I implement multiple connexions for same user via password client with Laravel Passport:

I have a mobile app, that needs to communicate with a Laravel based API. My users, at first launch of the app, will have to enter their `login` and `password` to get an `access_token`.

So I think that I need to put my password client `secret` in the code of my mobile app to be able to request tokens. But what if, my user has an iPhone and an iPad and he wants to login from both.

I'm asking because every time I make a request to `POST /oauth/token`, from the same `password_client`, every `access_token` of a certain `user` requested with my `password_client` gets `revoked`.

That would mean that, every time my user would use his iPad, he would be disconnected from his iPhone because the token wouldn't be valid anymore?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own Controller and Routes...

Passport has a defined "Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController" and there is a method called "issueToken()".

If you see the method below it calls the function "revokeOtherAccessTokens()", and this **deletes** or ***revoke*** all "access_tokens" using the "Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository"

So what you can do **is to write your own controller and prevent to call "revokeOtherAccessTokens()"**

**The fact that you must keep in mind is that the access tokens will never be pruned or revoked at least that the refresh token became issued or manually delete them.**

Refresh tokens and access tokens are revoked when refresh token is issued, because the "League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\RefreshTokenGrant" in method "respondToAccessTokenRequest()", it already revoke old "access_token" and "refresh_token", so we don't have to worry about revoke or delete them in this case.

```php
...
// Expire old tokens
$this->accessTokenRepository->revokeAccessToken($oldRefreshToken['access_token_id']);
$this->refreshTokenRepository->revokeRefreshToken($oldRefreshToken['refresh_token_id']);
...
```

> Here is an sample implementation, hope it helps:

*routes:*

```php
Route::post('oauth/access_token', 'Auth\OAuth2Controller@issueToken');
```

*customized controller:*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\HandlesOAuthErrors;

use Zend\Diactoros\Response as Psr7Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class OAuth2Controller extends Controller
{
    use HandlesOAuthErrors;

    /**
     * The authorization server.
     *
     * @var AuthorizationServer
     */
    protected $server;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  AuthorizationServer  $server
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationServer $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    /**
     * Authorize a client to access the user's account.
     *
     * @param  ServerRequestInterface  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        return $this->withErrorHandling(function () use ($request) {
            return $this->server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, new Psr7Response);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that Passport changed the way it was dealing with the Access Token creation and the method @issueToken in `AccessTokenController` does no longer revoke old tokens (check [Multiple Access Token](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/83)).

I think that this change was introduced before @jesús-lozano-m answer and therefore there is no longer the need to customize controller.

However, **if you want to revoke old tokens**, now you can do that by setting a listener to the Passport Event `AccessTokenCreated`.

app/Providers/eventServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    protected $listen = [
        'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
            'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens'
        ]
    ];
    public function boot() {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

app/Listeners/RevokeOldTokens.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated;
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class RevokeOldTokens {
    public function __construct() {
        //
    }
    public function handle(AccessTokenCreated $event) {
        $client = Client::find($event->clientId);
        // delete this client tokens created before one day ago:
        $client->tokens()
                  ->where('user_id', $event->userId)
                  ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay())
                  ->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  how can this be done in Lumen framework? It does not have  'find' method in \Laravel\Passport\Client

Answer (score 0):

I wirte below mention code in my **app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider** and its working. It won't removke old token and allow me login from multiple devicess

```
use Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport;

public function boot()
{
        $this->setPassportConfiguration();
}

private function setPassportConfiguration(): void
{
        LumenPassport::allowMultipleTokens();
}
```