# Laravel passport prevent user to login together with the same credential

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I was using Laravel Passport to allow my mobile to call laravel api for using laravel authentication.

I found a problem recently which is laravel passport allow the same user to login from multiple devices. Is there any solution for me to prevent the same user to login with other devices at the same time?

I have found a way to logout with Laravel Passport but I do not know if it is the best way if I use

```
$request->user()->token()->revoke()
```

whenever a user is trying to login.

Comment: I think you should revoke the already logged in token to let other login user from other device.

Comment: May be this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467566/laravel-passport-multiple-connexions-via-password-client/39802823#39802823

Comment: @MayankDudakiya seem like he had different case. He wanted concurrent login and I dont

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can hook the `AccessTokenCreated` event, and then inside your listener you can revoke any existing tokens.

Add these events/listeners to your `EventServiceProvider`

```php
'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
    'App\Listeners\RevokeExistingTokens',
],
```

Then create a listener using `php artisan make:listener RevokeExistingTokens`

Then inside the `handle` function:

```php
$user = User::find($event->userId);

$user->tokens()->offset(1)->get()->map(function ($token) {
    $token->revoke();
});
```

This will delete all of the users tokens except the one that was just created.

Answer (score 8):

Considering @Lucas Dalmarco comment on @atymic answer regarding MySQL "offset" command problem. Here is a workaround solution that can be implemented.

```
$user = User::find($event->userId);

$user->tokens()->limit(PHP_INT_MAX)->offset(1)->get()->map(function ($token) {
    $token->revoke();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

atymic answer is more than correct, but in some versions of MySQL the "offset" method can be problematic, so you can do that in "handle" function:

```
 Token::where('id', '!=', $event->tokenId)
    ->where('user_id', $event->userId)
    ->where('client_id', $event->clientId)
    ->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Passport provides already events for this purpose. Please check it out [document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#events)

Passport raises events when issuing access tokens and refresh tokens. You may use these events to prune or revoke other access tokens in your database. If you would like, you may attach listeners to these events in your application's App\Providers\EventServiceProvider class:

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Laravel\Passport\Events\AccessTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\RevokeOldTokens',
    ],

    'Laravel\Passport\Events\RefreshTokenCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\PruneOldTokens',
    ],
];
```